# Identify matched pairs and create a common key

Tags: r, match, key-value, matching

I have

```
df<-data.frame(record_id=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), var1=1:6, matched.with=rev(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))

> df
  record_id var1 matched.with
1         A    1            F
2         B    2            E
3         C    3            D
4         D    4            C
5         E    5            B
6         F    6            A
```

so, id `A` has been matched with `F`, `B` with `E`, `C` with `D`

I would like to create a `common.key` variable for the pairs like

```
df.common.key
  record_id var1 matched.with common.key
1         A    1            F          1
2         B    2            E          2
3         C    3            D          3
4         D    4            C          3
5         E    5            B          2
6         F    6            A          1
```

Which shows that `A` has been matched with `F` (row 1) with key `1` and `F` has been matched with `A` (row 6) with also key `1`. Common key does not have to be numeric, it can also be string or factor.

How can I accomplish this 1) if my data frame includes **only** matched pairs, 2) if my DF also includes observations *without* matched pairs 3) is there a tidyverse solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the unique combination of letters (in the same order) using `pmin` and `pmax`. Then, we can ust the `grp` column to create the `common.key`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = paste0(pmin(record_id, matched.with), pmax(record_id, matched.with))) %>% 
  mutate(common.key = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

**Output**

```
  grp   record_id  var1 matched.with common.key
  <chr> <chr>     <int> <chr>             <int>
1 AF    A             1 F                     1
2 BE    B             2 E                     2
3 CD    C             3 D                     3
4 CD    D             4 C                     3
5 BE    E             5 B                     2
6 AF    F             6 A                     1
```

Comment: Nice use of cur_group_id() . One question: why does pmin/pmax work with character vectors? What gets evaluated?

Comment: @ECII In general, R sorts things lexicographically. So, if you have a vector of random letters, then it will sort them in order. Or say you did `sort(c("A", 5, 1, "B", ""))`, then you would get `""  "1" "5" "A" "B"`. So, `pmin` will pull the letters at the beginning of the alphabet for `pmin`, then the opposite for `pmax`. In the case above, `pmin` returns `A`, `B`, and `C` values and `pmax` returns `D`, `E`, and `F`. So, when pasting them together, the letters are in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a temporary variable that pastes the strings from `record_id` and `matched.with` in alphabetical order (row-wise), then groups by that variable and selects the first `var1` to put in the `common.key`

```r
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(common = paste0(sort(c(record_id, matched.with)), collapse = '')) %>% 
  group_by(common) %>% 
  mutate(common.key = first(var1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-common)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> record_id  var1 matched.with common.key
#>   <chr>     <int> <chr>             <int>
#> 1 A             1 F                     1
#> 2 B             2 E                     2
#> 3 C             3 D                     3
#> 4 D             4 C                     3
#> 5 E             5 B                     2
#> 6 F             6 A                     1
```

Answer (score 2):

With a join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%   
  mutate(id = pmin(matched.with, record_id)) %>% 
  left_join(select(df, record_id, var1), by = c("id" = "record_id")) %>% 
  select(record_id, var1 = var1.x, matched.with, common.key = var1.y)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  record_id  var1 matched.with common.key
  <chr>     <int> <chr>             <int>
1 A             1 F                     1
2 B             2 E                     2
3 C             3 D                     3
4 D             4 C                     3
5 E             5 B                     2
6 F             6 A                     1
```

Answer (score 2):

We may also use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = str_c(pmin(record_id, matched.with), 
       pmax(record_id, matched.with))) %>% 
   mutate(common.key = first(var1)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  record_id  var1 matched.with common.key
  <chr>     <int> <chr>             <int>
1 A             1 F                     1
2 B             2 E                     2
3 C             3 D                     3
4 D             4 C                     3
5 E             5 B                     2
6 F             6 A                     1
```

Comment: Thanks. What does first() do? I added var1 as placeholder. There may be duplicates in var1. Is that a problem?

Comment: @ECII it returns the first value from 'var1' by group.  If it is not the case, then try `df %>% mutate(common.key =str_c(pmin(record_id, matched.with), 
       pmax(record_id, matched.with)), common.key = match(common.key, unique(common.key)))`